# Replace a NaN index value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, replace, nan

I'm new to Python and things in general are going pretty well. However, I've come across a problem that seems pretty simple, but it's killing me!

I have a dataframe with a NaN value in the index. I want to change this so that it makes more sense when I come to plotting it.

I have:

```
       Open
NaN    50
Yes    102
No     134
```

And all I want is to replace the NaN so I have:

```
               Open
No response    50
Yes            102
No             134
```

What's the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Index.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.fillna.html):

```
df.index = df.index.fillna('No response')
print (df)
              Open
No response     50
Yes            102
No             134
```

Comment: Amazing! It works and it's simple. I knew it had to be easy. You're a gentleman and a scholar!